# Elisp: assigning lists to variables

Tags: list, elisp

Am trying to understand lists and am confused as to why the second example (below) compiles but the first one doesn't.

In both examples, we (try to) compare each element in the list of characters (?a ?b ?c) for equality against ?a and the idea is that it returns (t nil nil).  The only difference between the two examples is that the second doesn't use an interim variable to hold the list).

What am I doing wrong?  (I checked my list assignment syntax against the GNU docs and I didn't see anything wrong...)

EDIT: My mistake was not paying attention to detail; as Stefan points out, the compile-time error is due to a parenthesis in the wrong place.  Sorry to disappoint if you came to this post looking to learn something about lists in Elisp.

Example #1 (does not compile):

```
(let (char-to-compare, char-list)
    (setq char-to-compare ?a)
    (setq char-list '(?a ?b ?c))
    (mapcar (lambda(element) (char-equal element char-to-compare)) char-list))
```

Example #2: (compiles and runs correctly):

```
(let (char-to-compare)
    (setq char-to-compare ?a)
    (mapcar (lambda(element) (char-equal element char-to-compare)) '(?a ?b ?c)))
```

Comment: `let` is not meant to just declare variables, but to also initialize them.  So use it: `(let ((char-to-compare ?a) (char-to-list '(?a ?b ?c)) ...)`.

Comment: Use the `TAB` key to indent your code.  That will tell you what's wrong.

Comment: thanks, *red face*, can pls you make your comment an answer so i can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the TAB key to indent your code. That will tell you what's wrong.